# Webflux better performance Mono<List<Object>>, Flux<Object>

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm starting with webflux and I wonder which of the following have a better performance as all of them seem quite similar to me

```
- List<Customer> findAll()
- Mono<List<Customer>> findAll()
- Flux<Customer> findAll()
```

Could you help me to understand which one is the best and why? Thanks

Comment: None of them are best, they all have different user cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty basic, and you should read about the difference between a `Mono`, a `Flux` and a concrete `List<T>` in the [official Reactive documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/). But i will explain it in simple terms.

All of the above produce the same thing, it's more of a question how they produce it.

All examples will assume that your application is under heavy load, or you have a very slow database.

### **List findAll()**

When this call is made, the underlying thread that performs the call, will call the database and then `wait` for the answer to be returned from the database. During this waiting, it will basically do nothing. It will sit there and do nothing until the database responds with the List of customers.

As you can understand, this is usually a waste of resources (memory) having threads just waiting for responses.

### **Mono<List> findAll()**

This type of call will call the database and ask for a List of customers, if the database is slow, here the thread will not wait it will actually start doing something else. Maybe do other calls to the database, or process something else its free for the server to decide. Here you could technically say that you are making a `async` call to the database and the thread is free to do anything else while the database is processing the request.

This makes the use of threads more efficient, making sure that all threads always has something to do.

When the response comes back from the database we deliver the entire `List<Customer>` out to the calling client.

### **Flux findAll()**

Here we ask for a list of Customers but we dont want our response as a full list in one go. Instead we are basically say "*give me all customers, but deliver them when you find them in a as-you-go manor*".

It doesn't hand you a giant list in one go as the two previous examples but instead it might first give you 8 customers, then 10, then another 8, then 15 in a flow until all Customers are delivered.

This is usually only noticeable for us humans if you have very large lists. If it is only a couple of entries to us it looks like the list got delivered in one go. But if you have millions of entries in the database you will notice the difference.

### Summary

The first example `List<T>` is a blocking call and should not be done in webflux at all. Webflux has very few threads, and will try to make use of them as efficient as possible. If your threads needs to wait for the database you risk having very poor performance.

Netty (the default underlying server implementation used in webflux) runs a set number of worker threads depending on how many cores your machine has. So having one thread waiting can be quite a huge performance loss.

Second example, if you have small lists and you want to deliver lists in one go, then `Mono<List<Customer>>` is a good choice. But a `Flux` can be useful here too.

Third example, large lists, continuous flow of items, if you have an application that constantly pushes out values to a client (web sockets) think of a gambling site that pushes odds, or a stock market application pushing a constant flow of data.

### Blocking db drivers

Lastly a word about database drivers. In order to use Mono, Flux against the database means you need to have a non-blocking database driver that supports the [R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc) standard.

If the database driver you are using does not follow it then all your calls will be like example one, and will be done in a blocking manor with poor performance.

There are ways to optimize such calls if you really need to talk to a db that does not support [R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc). But these sort of db's should be avoided if possible.